# Testing DHCP range; multiple addresses per interface

Tags: networking, dhcp, network-interface

I set up a DHCP server; I have a range defined, for ~1k hosts. Is there a way
to test all the addresses? This is the first time I have a task like this and
I would like to know what will happen when DHCP will lease all addresses, messages, etc.

Having one machine, is it possible to configure the interface to have 1k addresses? DHCP cannot serve to the same MAC multiple times, so this is not an option; VirtualBox has only 4 network adapters and I think I cannot add more. VLANs? 
Is this possible?

Best Regards,
Kamil

Comment: http://blog.thecybershadow.net/2013/01/10/dhcp-test-client/

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/dhquery/

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/171744/command-line-program-to-test-dhcp-service

Comment: AFAIK the maximum would be 4,294,967,294 IPv4 addresses per interface. Cheers.